# How to detect if string contains emoji in Java?

Tags: java, emoji

I would like to detect if a string contains emoji in Java.

I tried https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java but it is not maintained anymore and fails on new emojis.

For example - the following test fails:

```kotlin
EmojiManager.containsEmoji("This string contains beans ") shouldBe true
```

Comment: Maybe https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html?

Comment: Here is the full Wikipedia list of _[Unicode emojis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Unicode_blocks)_.  You'd have to map them; you could _[XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)_ the table, to create a list.

Comment: Contribute to the library by fixing it yourself? Looks like modifying [`/src/main/resources/emojis.json`](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java/blob/master/src/main/resources/emojis.json) is all that's needed.

Comment: You can adopt a whitelist or blacklist policy, depending on your use case. If your string should consist of ASCII only, then anything that's not ASCII is illegal (BLACKLIST). Alternatively, if you know what emojis may be present, you could scan for those (whitelist).

Comment: On which Java version are you?

Comment: You can check against the codepoints in the first column of [Basic Emojis](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/15.0/emoji-sequences.txt)

Answer (score 2):

In Java 21 you will be able to use [`Character#isEmoji(int)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isEmoji(int)) to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated answer, including the resource you provided within the comments.

It should be able to mimic the *containsEmoji* method, although, it is not fully tested.

I used the following resource, *[Unicode, Annex A – Emoji Properties and Data Files](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Properties_and_Data_Files)*.
Specifically, the *[emoji-data.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/15.0.0/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt)* data file.

I used the following *regex* to capture the values.

```
^([\dA-F]{4,5})(?:\.\.([\dA-F]{4,5}))?
```

And, a print value to compile the source.

```
list.add(new int[] { 0x$1, 0x$2 });\n
```

There will be several empty *$2* groups, so you'll need to use a *find-and-replace*.

I cannot paste all the code, as it is over *30,000* characters.

```java
public class EmojiUtil {
    static List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        /* https://unicode.org/Public/15.0.0/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt */
        list.add(new int[] { 0x0023 });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x002a });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x0030, 0x0039 });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x00a9 });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x00ae });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x203c });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x2049 });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x2122 });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x2139 });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x2194, 0x2199 });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x21a9, 0x21aa });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x231a, 0x231b });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x2328 });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x23cf });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x23e9, 0x23ec });
        list.add(new int[] { 0x23ed, 0x23ee });
        /* ... */
    }

    static boolean contains(String string) {
        char[] characters = string.toCharArray();
        char high, low;
        int index, limit;
        for (int[] values : list) {
            if (values.length == 1) limit = values[0];
            else limit = values[1];
            for (int codePoint = values[0]; codePoint <= limit; codePoint++) {
                if (codePoint > 0xffff) {
                    high = Character.highSurrogate(codePoint);
                    low = Character.lowSurrogate(codePoint);
                    if ((index = Arrays.binarySearch(characters, (char) high)) >= 0) {
                        if (index + 1 < characters.length && characters[index + 1] == (char) low)
                            return true;
                    }
                } else if (Arrays.binarySearch(characters, (char) values[0]) >= 0)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example

```java
EmojiUtil.contains("This string contains beans \uD83E\uDED8");
```

Comment: This is the relevant part of the documentation: https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Properties_and_Data_Files

Comment: From that source, I found, _https://www.unicode.org/Public/15.0.0/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt_.  In which, you can use the following regex to capture the ranges.  _^([\dA-F]{4,5})(?:\.\.([\dA-F]{4,5}))?_

Comment: @pixel, I've updated my answer, let me know if you're able to get it to work.